# Spartacus SERVER_REQUEST_ORIGIN resolves wrong protocol in SSR

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

We have an issue with the wrong protocol detection in the next configuration:

1. The Spartacus application is running inside a Docker container.
2. We use Google Cloud and Kubernetes.
3. The Spartacus application pod has only http protocol configured, the load balancer is responsible for SSL (https) configuration.

The issue is that the browser resolves url with https protocol, but in the `core-libs/setup/ssr/express-utils/express-request-origin.ts` -> `getRequestOrigin` the protocol will be detected as http, because it is coming with the request object(this is request between load balancer and Docker instance and it will be always done via http, not https).

I see that in the `getRequestOrigin` the host should be taken from the `X-Forwarded-Host`, is there a reason why the protocol is not taken in the same way from the `X-Forwarded-Proto`?

If the protocol will be taken from the `X-Forwarded-Proto` - it will resolve our issue.

I did try overwriting the `getRequestOrigin`, but it requires me to rewrite the other providers.
This solution works fine, but it increases the complexity of the project maintenance.